# Send back a response after post request

Tags: ios, swift, post

First of all, I do not think this is possible but I have got a piece of code that does the post request to a database and I would like to get a response depending on the data posted. I mean, if the variables are put in the db, the response will be "ok", else, it will be "no".

My post request is the following:

```
let postDataURL = "https://www.webpage.com/login_app.php"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: postDataURL)!
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url as URL)

let paramString = "precio=\(precio)&texto=\(texto)&user=\(user)&l_origen=\(l_origen)&l_destino=\(l_destino)&num_pal=\(num_pal)"
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (response, data, error) in
    print(response!)

    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if statusCode==200 {
            print("Connection Successful")    
        } else {
            print("Connection Failed (!200)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the `php` side I could have something like

```
if (affected_rows > 0){
    $response = "ok";
} else {
    $response = "no";
}
```

But after that, I do not know how would the php code reconnect to the device to give it the response.

Thank you so much for your time.

**EDIT**

Response sent when it fails:

```
Optional(<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Log in - Siens Translation</title>

.
.
.

</body>
</html>
)
```

Which is basically the html part of the page.

**PHP part**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
require "class.logsys.php";

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

session_start();
\Fr\LS::init();

if(isset($_POST['action_login'])){
  $identification = $_POST['login'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  if($identification == "" || $password == ""){
    $msg = array("Error", "Username / Password Wrong !");
  }else{
    $login = \Fr\LS::login($identification, $password,     isset($_POST['remember_me']));
    if($login === false){
      $msg = array("Error", "Username / Password Wrong !");
    }else if(is_array($login) && $login['status'] == "blocked"){
      $msg = array("Error", "Too many login attempts. You can attempt login     after ". $login['minutes'] ." minutes (". $login['seconds'] ." seconds)");
    }
  }
}


  $precio = $_POST['precio']; 

  $texto = $_POST['texto'];

  $texto_ant = $_POST['texto_ant']; 

  $user = $_POST['user']; 

  $pass = $_POST['pass'];

  $l_origen = $_POST['l_origen']; 

  $l_destino = $_POST['l_destino'];

  $num_pal = $_POST['num_pal']; 

  $modificado = $_POST['modificado'];

$login = \Fr\LS::login($user, $pass, false, false);
if($login === true){

 define('HOST','');
 define('USER','');
 define('PASS','');
 define('DB','');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');

 if($modificado!='Si'){

 $sql = "UPDATE users SET precio='$precio', text_cli='$texto',     l_origen='$l_origen', l_destino='$l_destino', num_pal='$num_pal' WHERE     username='$user' AND text_cli='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  echo '{"success":true}';

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
  $sql2 = "UPDATE users SET precio2='$precio', text_cli2='$texto',  l_origen2='$l_origen', l_destino2='$l_destino', num_pal2='$num_pal' WHERE  username='$user' AND text_cli2='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
 } 

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0) {
  $sql3 = "UPDATE users SET precio3='$precio', text_cli3='$texto',     l_origen3='$l_origen', l_destino3='$l_destino', num_pal3='$num_pal' WHERE     username='$user' AND text_cli3='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0) {
  $sql4 = "UPDATE users SET precio4='$precio', text_cli4='$texto',  l_origen4='$l_origen', l_destino4='$l_destino', num_pal4='$num_pal' WHERE  username='$user' AND text_cli4='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0) {
  $sql5 = "UPDATE users SET precio5='$precio', text_cli5='$texto',  l_origen5='$l_origen', l_destino5='$l_destino', num_pal5='$num_pal' WHERE username='$user' AND text_cli5='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql5);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0) {
  $sql6 = "UPDATE users SET precio6='$precio', text_cli6='$texto', l_origen6='$l_origen', l_destino6='$l_destino', num_pal6='$num_pal' WHERE username='$user' AND text_cli6='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql6);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0) {
  $sql7 = "UPDATE users SET precio7='$precio', text_cli7='$texto', l_origen7='$l_origen', l_destino7='$l_destino', num_pal7='$num_pal' WHERE username='$user' AND text_cli7='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql7);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0) {
  $sql8 = "UPDATE users SET precio8='$precio', text_cli8='$texto', l_origen8='$l_origen', l_destino8='$l_destino', num_pal8='$num_pal' WHERE    username='$user' AND text_cli8='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql8);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0) {
  $sql9 = "UPDATE users SET precio9='$precio', text_cli9='$texto', l_origen9='$l_origen', l_destino9='$l_destino', num_pal9='$num_pal' WHERE username='$user' AND text_cli9='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql9);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0) {
  $sql10 = "UPDATE users SET precio10='$precio', text_cli10='$texto', l_origen10='$l_origen', l_destino10='$l_destino', num_pal10='$num_pal' WHERE username='$user' AND text_cli10='' LIMIT 1 ";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql10);
  echo '{"success":false}';
 }

 $sql11 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli='' AND role='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";

 mysqli_query($con,$sql11);

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql12 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli2='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli2='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql12);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql13 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli3='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli3='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql13);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql14 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli4='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli4='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql14);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql15 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli5='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli5='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql15);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql16 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli6='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli6='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql16);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql17 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli7='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli7='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql17);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql18 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli8='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli8='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql18);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql19 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli9='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli9='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql19);
 }

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql20 = "UPDATE users SET text_cli10='$texto' WHERE ((l_origen='$l_origen' || l_origen2='$l_origen') AND l_destino='$l_destino' AND text_cli10='' AND role ='trad_app') LIMIT 1 ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql20);
 }

}

 if($modificado=='Si'){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli`='$texto', `l_origen` = '$l_origen',  `precio` = '$precio', `l_destino` = '$l_destino', `num_pal` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli2`='$texto', `l_origen2` = '$l_origen', `precio2` = '$precio', `l_destino2` = '$l_destino', `num_pal2` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli2 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli3`='$texto', `l_origen3` = '$l_origen', `precio3` = '$precio', `l_destino3` = '$l_destino', `num_pal3` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli3 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli4`='$texto', `l_origen4` = '$l_origen', `precio4` = '$precio', `l_destino4` = '$l_destino', `num_pal4` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli4 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli5`='$texto', `l_origen5` = '$l_origen', `precio5` = '$precio', `l_destino5` = '$l_destino', `num_pal5` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli5 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli6`='$texto', `l_origen6` = '$l_origen', `precio6` = '$precio', `l_destino6` = '$l_destino', `num_pal6` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli6 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli7`='$texto', `l_origen7` = '$l_origen', `precio7` = '$precio', `l_destino7` = '$l_destino', `num_pal7` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli7 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli8`='$texto', `l_origen8` = '$l_origen', `precio8` = '$precio', `l_destino8` = '$l_destino', `num_pal8` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli8 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli9`='$texto', `l_origen9` = '$l_origen', `precio9` = '$precio', `l_destino9` = '$l_destino', `num_pal9` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli9 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `text_cli10`='$texto', `l_origen10` = '$l_origen', `precio10` = '$precio', `l_destino10` = '$l_destino', `num_pal10` = '$num_pal'  WHERE text_cli10 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = ''";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   }

 $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli='$texto' WHERE text_cli = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";

 mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli2='$texto' WHERE text_cli2 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli3='$texto' WHERE text_cli3 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli4='$texto' WHERE text_cli4 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli5='$texto' WHERE text_cli5 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli6='$texto' WHERE text_cli6 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli7='$texto' WHERE text_cli7 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli8='$texto' WHERE text_cli8 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli9='$texto' WHERE text_cli9 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

  if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)==0){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET text_cli10='$texto' WHERE text_cli10 = '$texto_ant' AND `role` = 'trad_app' ";
   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }

 }

 mysqli_close($con);

  }

?>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Log in - Siens Translation</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="ordenador/ingles/css_imagenes/favicon.ico"  type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ordenador/ingles/css_imagenes/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link href="ordenador/ingles/nuestra_firma_estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="ordenador/ingles/css/style4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="movil/castellano/menu/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="ordenador/ingles/css_resolutions/resolution800x600.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="ordenador/ingles/css_resolutions/resolution1024x600.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="ordenador/ingles/css_resolutions/resolution1366x768.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="ordenador/ingles/css_resolutions/resolution1280x600.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="ordenador/castellano/area_clientes/css/css_login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="movil/castellano/menu/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>


<div class="menu_bar" style="font-family:'Gotham-Bold';">
<a class="bt-menu" style="font-size:600%; font-family:'Gotham-Bold'"><span     class="icon-menu"></span>Siens App<br><p  style="font-size:25%; font- family:'Gotham-Light';">From</p></a>
</div>

<div id="login">
  <div id="centrar_app">
  <form action="login_app.php" method="POST" style="margin:0px auto;display:table;">
    <label>
      <p style="font-size:600%">Log in </p><br><br><br>
    </label>
    <label>  
      <p style="font-size:400%">Username</p><br>
      <input style="padding-left:15px; border: 2px solid #475678; font-size:200%; height:100%" id="cuadro" name="login" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['user'])){ $user = $_GET['user']; echo $user; } ?>" />
    </label><br><br><br>
    <label>
      <p style="font-size:400%">Password</p><br>
      <input style="padding-left:15px; border: 2px solid #475678; font-size:200%; height:100%" id="cuadro" name="password" type="password" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['pass'])){ $pass = $_GET['pass']; echo $pass; } ?>" />
    </label><br><a style="color:white; text-decoration:underline" href="ordenador/castellano/area_clientes/forgotpass.php">Forgot password?</a><br><br>
    <label>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" /> Remember me
      </p>
    </label><br>
    <div clear></div>
    <button id="login-button" style="font-size:400%;" 
            name="action_login">Access</button><br><br>
  </form>

  <style>
    input[type=text], input[type=password]{
      width: 230px;
    }
  </style>

  <button id="login-button" style="font-size:400%"  
            onclick="location.href='';">Register</button><br><br>
    <div id="thawteseal" style="text-align:center;" title="Click to Verify - This site chose Thawte SSL for secure e-commerce and confidential communications.">
    <div><script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.thawte.com/getthawteseal?host_name=&amp;size=S&amp;lang=en"></script></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="login">
   <div id="centrar_app">
  <a onMouseOver="this.style.color='white'">If you can't access our payment zone Gateway, you need to deactivate "Block Cookies" in your iPhone configuration settings.</a>
</div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:10rem" align="center">
<img style="width: 20%; height: 20%" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: It does not have to *"reconnect"* at all, a POST is not fire-and-forget, your server has the chance to do exactly what you want. It can simply reply with what you want which will be part of the `response` or `data`.

Comment: @luk2302 Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @Steeve because I can type comments quicker and do not have to be as careful with the writing - nonetheless I now posted an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your server does not have to "reconnect" to the device / client at all, a POST is not fire-and-forget. The client has an open connection to the server sending its request and waiting for a response from the server.

Your server has the chance to do exactly what you want. It can simply reply with what you want - that result will be part of the `response` or `data` in the callback of `sendAsynchronousRequest`. Right now your php code is not printing anything, but try to `echo` something, set a breakpoint inside the swift callback and inspect what the callback objects contain and how they relate to what you `echo`ed on the server.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using URLSession:

PHP side:

```
if (affected_rows > 0) {
    echo '{"success":true}';
 }else{
     echo '{"success":false}';
 }
```

Swift side:

```
    let url=URL(string: "https://www.webpage.com/login_app.php");
    var request=URLRequest(url:url!)
    request.httpMethod="POST"
    let postString = "precio=\(precio)&texto=\(texto)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task=URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil else {
            print("no data found")
            return
        }

        do{
            if let jsonData=try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary{
                print(jsonData)
                let success=jsonData.value(forKey: "success") as! Bool
                if success{
                    print("login succeded")
                 }else{
                    print("login failed")
                }
            }else{
                print("could not parse json")
                let json_str=NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                 print("Failed to parse json:", json_str)
            }
        }catch{
            print("request failed")
            let json_str=NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print(json_str)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

**-EDIT**
Since it's not working, try changing your POST request this way:

```
let url=URL(string: "https://www.webpage.com/login_app.php")
var request=URLRequest(url:url!)
request.httpMethod="POST"
request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let params=["precio":precio, "texto":texto]
let body=NSMutableData()
for (key, value) in params {
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
}
request.httpBody=body
```

**-EDIT2**
And here's my NSMutableData extension:

```
extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(_ string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue), allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is basically a link-only answer, please include the relevant part of your linked answer in this answer or vote to close this question as duplicate. If the other answer gets deleted this answer will be useless as well (not something you would want)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I will try the code.

Comment: Sorry for late answer @MarieDm but it did not work. It shows "request failed" even though the post is done correctly to the database.

Comment: Did you also modified your php code as I showed you @alberzyzz?

Comment: Yes I did. It is strange, I don't know what could be failing @MarieDm

Comment: Thank you for your time. It shows me "Use of unresolved identifier 'boundary'"

Comment: Yes sorry, it's a string I generate: let boundary="Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

Comment: Hi Marie, this solved it, same happens for "value of type NSMutabledata has no member append string"

Comment: Hi @alberzyzz, I added my extension to complete the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and dedication. It is still showing "request failed" even though the data is being posted in the database correctly.

Comment: Meaning the PHP request works but there is a problem when returning the response. If "request failed" is printed, it's probably because the response is not at the right format, then it can't be decoded. The problem probably comes from the PHP. I'm sorry to ask again, but are you sure you return the exact same code I wrote: echo '{"success":true}';

Comment: Also @alberzyzz, I edited my answer to print the returned response when the request fails. That might help us to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi Marie! I edited the original post with the response sent. And yes, I confirm I have written exactly echo '{"success":true}';

Comment: @alberzyzz did you print the returned response?

Comment: I think the problem comes from you php file. I don't think it should contain html. But I can't know where the problem comes from without seeing it all.

Comment: @alberzyzz I don't see the point of the html code in your php script. You don't need it when you call the script from your iOS client and that's why it is returned (instead of just the php echo part). I suggest your remove it. If you need it (to display on a web browser for example, you should deal this in a separate script).

Comment: @alberzyzz anything new?